# Study of embryos

Tags: biology, medicine

I want to know how different stages of human development were elucidated. What experiments were done? Do they involve taking out zygotes, embryos, and fetuses at different stages? How could one study all these stages in development of one individual? Does this mean that many developing humans were examined?

I don't think MRI could have helped because it was discovered a bit later.

Comment: Early research was conducted on animals (e.g., deer), not on humans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some references; for Ancient science, see :

- James Wilberding, *Embryology*, **Ch.20** of Georgia Irby (editor), [A Companion to Science Technology and Medicine in Ancient Greece and Rome](https://books.google.it/books?id=Y_JvCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA329) (2016); see Aristotle ([GenAnim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_of_Animals) 773a1–2) and [Galen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galen) (*On the Formation of the Fetus* 54.13–14).

For Early Modern science, see :

- Paula Findlen, *Anatomy Theaters, Botanical Gardens, and Natural History Collections*, **Ch.12** of Katharine Park (editor), [The Cambridge History of Science. Vol.3 : Early Modern Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=2kvjAp92zcYC&pg=PA272); see [Vesalius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Vesalius).

For [William Harvey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Harvey#On_Animal_Generation), see [Walter Pagel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walter_Pagel)'s studies :

- [William Harvey's Biological Ideas : Selected Aspects and Historical Background](https://books.google.it/books?id=m0cQQlZK43cC&pg=PA7) (1967),
- [New Light on William Harvey](https://books.google.it/books?id=YZzkaAevzAoC&pg=PR5) (1976).

See also :

- [Joseph Needham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Needham) (with Arthur Hughes), [A History of Embryology](https://books.google.it/books?id=rRZEBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA7) (1st ed, 1934).